# Create TextView from template XML file

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a template of simple `TextView` in a file `simple_txt.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" >
</TextView>
```

In some code I need to create a `TextView` from this template, something like:

```
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
txt.setLayout(R.layout.simple_txt);//???
```

then do something with it (`setText` etc.). How can I create a `TextView` like this?

Comment: But why??, why not just get the TextView with findViewById() ????

Comment: cause i havent this text view in main layout, i need to create it from template file and then add to main layout

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
TextView txt = (TextView) View.inflate(this, R.layout.simple_txt, null);
```

Comment: fyi, generally passing null for last (root) param is not recommended but doing so is is essential here.